# C - Estruturas para ponto, linha poligonal e polígono

Tags: c, struct

Boa noite

O exercício pede pra que eu implemente três structs: Ponto (coordenadas X e Y), linhas poligonais (sequência de 2 a 100 pontos que são os vértices ao longo da linha) e polígono (sequência de 3 a 100 pontos que são os vértices ao longo do polígono sendo que o último coincide com o primeiro).

Eu implementei a struct para os pontos da seguinte forma:

```
typedef struct //Estrutura definida para os pontos.
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Ponto;
```

Para as linhas poligonais eu defini da seguinte forma, porém não sei se é o correto e se é a melhor forma.

```
 typedef struct //Estrutura definida para as linhas poligonais.
 {
     Ponto Vertice;
 } Linha;
```

Já para os polígonos eu não tive uma ideia de como fazer. Mas sei que a diferença entre uma linha poligonal e um polígono é que, para o polígono, a última e primeira coordenada são as mesmas (tem como eu especificar isso já dentro da struct?). Gostaria de ter uma ideia de como proceder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de você não precisar disso para a resposta de sua questão, uma linha é definida por dois pontos : ponto de início e de fim. Portanto, deveria ser :

```
typedef struct {
    Ponto p0, p1;
} Linha;
```

Uma linha poligonal (`polyline` ou `polilinha`) consiste de vários pontos, cada dois consecutivos formando um segmento. Como no seu problema você tem no máximo 100 elementos, podemos definir uma linha poligonal como:

```
typedef struct {
    int n_pontos; /* quantidade de pontos usados nessa polyline */
    Ponto p[100]; /* vetor com os pontos usados */
} Polilinha;
```

Um polígono é um caso especial de polilinha, no qual o último vértice se liga ao primeiro vértice. Por exemplo, para representar um triângulo, preciso definir três pontos; digamos que tenhamos o triângulo `(0,0) , (3,0) , (0,4)`, isso é o suficiente para deduzir a existência dos seguintes segmentos:

```
 (0,0) -> (3,0)
 (3,0) -> (0,4)
 (0,4) -> (0,0)
```

Se esses mesmos três pontos tivessem sidos passados para uma polilinha (nessa mesma ordem), os segmentos seriam:

```
 (0,0) -> (3,0)
 (3,0) -> (0,4)
```

Portanto, internamente, você pode representar com a mesma estrutura, porém deve manipular de forma distinta; daí:

```
typedef Polilinha Poligono;
```

Comment: Valeu Jefferson! Esqueci que preciso definir a quantidade de pontos da reta dentro da própria estrutura. No caso dos polígonos, ao dizer manipular, você quis dizer manipular dentro do próprio programa, certo?

Comment: Isso, manipular no sentido de usar funções / acessar seus valores